# Use random number generator in excel to provide me numbers with specific range

Tags: excel, random, statistics, data-analysis, poisson

I am using the excel tool named "Data Analysis" -> Random number Generation and generating 100 numbers for the "Poisson" distribution. I am entering the following values in each box: "Number of Variables: 1", "Number of Random Numbers: 100", "Distribution: Poisson", and "Lambda: 5". It outputs most of the numbers from 0 to 10 as I want them. However, when I use the "countif" statement to get how many 0's,1's,2's, and so on are there, I should see that the total counted is equal to 100 because every value generated is between 0 and 10, but no. The count comes up to be sometimes 91,88,or any other number because it exceeds 10 in the random generation.

How do I keep the range from 0 to 10 no matter what distribution I use whether it is Poisson or any other one from that list?

Comment: a poisson distribution is not restricted to 0 to 10. You are asking for a different distribution. Please be more specific as to the desired properties of the random output.

Comment: `=randbetween` will give you random numbers in a set boundary, but it will not be a poison distribution.

Comment: @ForwardEd Yea I already have randbetween, which is different. Why can't I have poisson distribution that gives me a range from 0-10. I mean it does give almost everytime 90 or above for the total. Well, right now I have 98....that's so close to 100. There are only 2 numbers that are not between 0-10

Comment: "Why can't I have poisson distribution that gives me a range from 0-10."  Because then it's not a Poisson distribution, by definition, since the support for Poissons is the set of all positive integers.

Answer (score 0):

Because the Poisson distribution has a REALLY long tail, sampling values from such a distribution will not be limited.  You can, however, discard any samples outside limits in a separate step.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to go out on a limb here and say that is the nature of the beast when dealing with statistics.  You are going to get outliers.  In this [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/poisson-distribution.html) we see that the poison plot with Lambda =5 has points greater than 10.